# What electric charges do the $SU(2)$ weak isospin bosons carry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, charge, electroweak, isospin-symmetry

The $SU(2)$ weak isospin group has three bosons, before symmetry breaking: The $W^1$, $W^2$, and $W^3$ weak isospin bosons.

The $W^1$ and $W^2$ mix to form the $W^+$ and $W^-$ bosons with electric charges $+1$ and $-1$, respectively.

So far, I can assume that the $W^3$ boson carries a neutral charge. However, I am not sure what the electric charges (which are somewhat present before the photon exists) of the $SU(2)$ triplet bosons ($W^1$, $W^2$, and $W^3$) are.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SU(2)), the $SU(2)$ triplet bosons form a Weak Isospin triplet (so one boson has Weak Isospin $+1$, another one has $-1$, and the last one has 0). Also, the formula for electric charge is $Q=T_3+\frac12 Y_w$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$W^1,W^2$ do not have well defined electric charge. They are not charge eigenstates:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Q|W^1\rangle&=+i|W^2\rangle\\
Q|W^2\rangle&=-i|W^1\rangle
\end{aligned}
$$

On the other hand, $W^\pm\propto W^1\pm iW^2$ do have well-defined charge:
$$
Q|W^\pm\rangle=\pm |W^\pm\rangle
$$

Comment: (+1) Thanks, but do you know what Hypercharge and Weak Isospin each SU(2) boson has?

Comment: $W^\pm$ has $T_3=\pm1$, and $W^3$ has $T_3=0$. They all have zero hypercharge.

Comment: $W^\pm$ don't have well defined isospin, but their hypercharge is zero.

Comment: $W^\pm$ or $W^{1,2}$?

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig ah, yes. I meant $W^{1,2}$. Thanks!